# how to set a default value to kendo ui dropdown?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using a kendo UI DropDownList control, how can we set a default value to the DropDownList?

I have a selected list property in viewmodel as following :

```
public SelectList AuditTypes { get; set; }
```

Then in controller I am populating the selected list and setting it to a default value

```
viewModel.AuditTypes = new SelectList(dropdownDetails, "Value", "Text", dropdownDetails.Where(x => x.Default == true));
```

and in my razor view I have the following code :

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("AuditType")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .BindTo(Model.AuditTypes)                     
                    .AutoBind(true)
```

The problem is that the default value is not being set.

Comment: Can you use DropDownListFor(m => m.AuditTypeId)?

Comment: That's not really using Kendo though, I am curious as to how to achieve this with Kendo

Comment: KendoUI also has a `DropDownListFor(x=>x.value)` version, so Longball27's suggestion is valid (and preferable in Razor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess, try .Value(YOUR_VALUE) in your chain

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-value

**Note:-** Make sure to pass the ValueField and not the TextField in the .Value() property of Kendo Control as "YOUR_VALUE" has to be an integer property as .Value() accepts an integer and not a text property, 
otherwise it won't work, it won't show any error but it won't give you the desired result.